# ESP32 How to change default port of AsyncWebServer from 80 to any other port number

Tags: esp32

I have application that I need to run multiple ESP32s in same network which publishes webserver, in my case multi device is broadcasting in same port as 80. This causing port issue I guess because only one device at a time is working on browser. When I change port number to 8080, I cannot make it work. Is there any configuration that I need to do before working with multi webserver?

I shared the code below which working, my purpose is make it work with multi device in same network.

```
#include <ESPmDNS.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
  
const char* ssid = "XXXX";
const char* password =  "XXXX";
  
AsyncWebServer server(80);
  
void setup(){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }
 
  if(!MDNS.begin("esp32")) {
     Serial.println("Error starting mDNS");
     return;
  }
  
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  
  server.on("/hello", HTTP_GET, [](AsyncWebServerRequest *request){
    request->send(200, "text/plain", "Hello World");
  });
  
  server.begin();
}
  
void loop(){}
```

Comment: You need to use a different name for each ESP32. Change "esp32" to something unique for each device in the call to `MDNS.begin()`. Changing the port number isn't going to help when you have multiple devices advertising the same name.

Comment: I was actually doing that but still having same problem then I realized that I was sending more than 20 messages per sec to browser. That was the problem. So I reschedule my messages as 10 per sec and it is working like a charm now., thanks.